# Is there a way to dynamically delete a row from a table after a certain period of time?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a row from my table after 12 hours have passed from the row being created.

I have a dateTime column in my table which records the time at which it was created, is there a way to delete a row after 12 hours dynamically? Another problem this creates is that the date may change during the 12 hours, which may render the timestamp of the row irrelevant.

I have tried to do some simple SQL Queries from examples I have found on similar questions although I do not know how to deal with the date-change aspect of the problem.

Example Queries:

```
DELETE FROM detail1 WHERE date < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');
```

Here is my table:

```
ID   |Position|  dateApplied    
 1   |  1     |  2019-07-20 05:23:16
 2   |  2     |  2017-07-20 12:13:30
```

I would like to find a query to help me delete each row after 12 hours.

Comment: after executing that query whats happening ?

Comment: Can't you simply add a column for the creation datetime that would be immutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a script and call it periodically with [Cron Jobs](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/), In that script check all the rows and delete expired ones.
It's easier if you save "expiry time" in the tabale:

```
$expireAfter = time() + (12 * 60 * 60); // time returns number of seconds since the Unix Epoch
```

Then in the periodic script, you can check if the row is expired or not:

```
$now = time();
$queryString = "DELETE FROM detail1 WHERE `expiry_time` < $now;";
```

With this approach, you don't need to worry about changing the date.